# Careless uninterested potential advisor

Tags: advisor

A professor, call **X**, who is with strong probability about to be my future MS Thesis supervisor/advisor, seems very interested to work with me. Mostly on lectures, **X** seems interested in my ideas and is very encouraging.

However, out of the class, **X** is totally unreachable, uninterested in my problems. e.g. very slow to respond questions, once I needed an important paperwork to be done and X totally slacked it, although a ceratin mouthful "sure I will do it" promise. I had really hardtime to fix related issue with much frustations, because of **X**'s attitude. And **X** did not give me any apologies for this situation.

I understand that profs are busy beings, managing tons of stuff at the same time, but I expect not to break a given promise or not to give promise at all to do something. I am really fed up and tired of this repeating behavior.

I have started to think that, it is not a good idea to work with **X**. I seriously doubt that professor would be reachable in my thesis study, not to mention to be helpful in my future academic pursuits, such as a strong letter for a Ph.D. application.

Am I expecting a lot ? Also, I want to kindly inform **X** that, I do not want to involve any future studies with **X**. What kind of wording should I use ?

Comment: I'd suggest you narrow this down as much as you can. There's at least two questions in here: 1) Are you expecting too much interaction from a thesis supervisor (potential or current really). 2) How do you decline previous acceptance of supervision.

Answer (score 13):

Professors are busy and are always juggling multiple commitments.

This does not mean that you are unimportant to them but maybe some judicious memory jogging is required for them to remember what X has promised you.

Another excellent strategy which I have adopted is to show up to my committee members' open office hours with issues when I need them solved instead of bothering them over email. Usually I need 5-10 minutes of their time to explain my issue and solicit future directions. That works really well. I am not a big fan of long meetings.

In response to your specific question, if you want to not work with X just tell X that you do not feel that you can work with them in the future. It might be helpful to have someone else lined up before you do so though.

Comment: What are "**open** office hours"? I know office hours for courses.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, office hours are office hours. Anyone can show up to them irrespective of whether you are in that course or not. Some faculty go above and beyond and make that explicit. Usually, that is referred to as "open office hours"

Comment: +1 for judicious memory jogging, overextended is not uninterested.

Answer (score 9):

> Also, I want to kindly inform X that, I do not want to involve any
>   future studies with X. What kind of wording should I use?

No wording should be used. Don't send anything.

Now you may be very angry or upset, but there is no point to send a message to imply you will never work with this person. If the professor does try to contact you for possible projects or studies, just simply say thanks, and proceed with saying that you have thought about this and have decided to pursue other options.

If you send a no-involvement-in-future message, you'd just end up looking obnoxious. This is not grade school, we don't tell everyone that "I am not going to play with you, and don't you dare inch your elbow over the side of my desk, or I am going to tell the Dean."

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Shion's answer: Sometimes, I could be X... And the reason is described in Shions excellent answer. It does not mean X is uninterested, but there are important and pressing tasks which easily cover 60h/week in my position, and then there are still the not-so-urgent-but-still-important tasks left.

I usually tell the students to remind me again if I did not do what I promised until xyz, and if they don't do that, I assume it was unimportant (well, usually I try to do what I promised, but still, things are slipping through).

I would suggest talking to your potential supervisor and (politely) talk about your concerns. If they don't get your point, it is totally ok to look for an other one and they can not be surprised. If they get your point, you should try to find some arrangement which would help you in similar situation (e.g. you are allowed to be a pain in the ass of your supervisor). For good students whose work I value, I really want them to push me. On the other hand, I definitely don't want to micro-manage someone. So it's a matter of balance and communication about it helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to students.  Always talk to students of the Prof.  If you start finding out lots of previous students dropped out, don't go that route.  If they look at you and say "run" follow their advice.  If it's clear that they are trying to not say something bad about their supervisor but clearly aren't willing to say anything good: stay away.

But don't burn bridges.  Just go for other options.  No need to say, "I'm sorry you're too busy".  Just you've gotten interested in another problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not obvious how this professor will look into your PhD. You also say he can be good and devote enough attention when he thinks this is appropriate (during the lecture).

The most obvious way to decide is to look around. Does the professor have other PhD students? Not very good if you would be the only one over many years. Which percent of these PhD students been successful? Maybe you can talk with them?

Also, that are most serious works of the professor laboratory? Recent *Science* or ten years without publications? Of course, asking such things directly is very tricky but try to visit the laboratory website.

Understanding the professors overall attitude to exactly PhD work may help to decide. Heavy involvement into ongoing research projects and other relevant activities (so no time for general talking, etc) may actually represent the professor positively.